# Casino games using bitcoins

Tags: client, gambling

I have a new question about the ability to play and to use the bitcoin for that.
Can one play online casino games using the bitcoin currency ?

Thanks

Comment: I decided to close this question but leave some other questions that were specifically about provably fair gaming open. This one is very broad and asks for _any_ business that accepts Bitcoin in a specific field. Provably fair gaming is a concept more closely related to Bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can play casino games using bitcoins just make sure that the particular casino you are playing for accepts bitcoin.

There are a lot of bitcoin casino online what matter is that you have to find which bitcoin casino fits for you and the one that you can truly understand.

Answer (score 0):

- https://www.luckybitcoincasino.com
- https://satoshibet.com

to list just a few !!! there are many online casinos accepting Bitcoin. :) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can and it even better than playing for $ because you can play casino games without registering to the site and without downloading any software for playing, although not all sites gives this option but there a few sites that you can play there instantly and the withdraw of your wins (if there are any .. :-) ) are almost instant as well.
you can try this  [bitcoin casino](http://www.thebitgames.com/)  web site, which i personally like and played there a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few now, but a couple of things to keep in mind when betting with BTC.

- Because BTC is impossible to charge back, make sure the site is legit before sending any coin
- The standard that you should look for is Provably Fair
- What is the process for collecting your winnings? Is it instant?
- Lots of BTC games are random number based (dice, lotto, coin flip, etc) if you're looking for real casino games like Blackjack, Poker, Craps, etc. check out these recommendations:

[DoubleDownBTC](http://doubledownbtc.com) - Blackjack

[Seals With Clubs](http://sealswithclubs.eu) - Poker

Comment: Are you affiliated with doubledownBTC? I noticed that the [whois record](http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/results.jsp?domain=doubledownbtc.com) was just updated, which makes me think it's a new site, and you posted links to it in three answers: [1](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13319/6242), [2](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13317/6242), [3](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13316/6242). Be sure to read the section [here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) about overt self-promotion, which isn't welcome here. Any affiliation should be disclosed.

Comment: Still it is one of the more useful answers on this question. I voted to close the question, due to "product recommendation request".

Comment: @Murch Usually, if an answer is useful without a spam link, I just remove the spam link and don't touch the rest of the answer. The link itself isn't useful because it's not an unbiased recommendation of the site (far from it).